# Non-independent two consecutive draws from two urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose there are two urns: in urn A, there are r red balls and w white balls. In urn B, there are b black balls.

Suppose we do the following experiment: draw k balls from urn A. Among those k balls, put only the red balls in urn B, and draw n balls from urn B. Then the number of red balls from the second draw is a random variable.

Call the random variable $\tilde{y}$. Then
\begin{align*}
Pr(\tilde{y}=y)=\sum\limits_{x=\max\{y,k-w\}}^{\min\{r,k\}}\frac{{r\choose x}{w\choose k-x}}{{r+w \choose k}}\frac{{x\choose y}{b\choose l-y}}{{x+b\choose l}}
\end{align*}

Does anyone know what the mean and the variance of this random variable are? If you do not know the exact form, what about the asymptotic mean and variance when r, w and b go to infinity with the ratio amongst them constant.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use $E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]]$ and $Var[Y] = Var[E[Y|X]] + E[Var[Y|X]]$ to get simpler summations for the mean and variance.

Comment: Label the red balls $1,\dots,r$ and let $y_i$ be $1$ if red ball $i$ is chosen via this process, and zero otherwise. Then $y=\sum y_i$. But $E(y_i)=E(y_j)$, so $E(y)=rE(y_1)$. And it is easy to compute $E(y_1)$